App Script Runtime Issue: Exception: Document is missing
This is my first time running app script. I have the following code to extract a bookmarked section from a google doc into a cell in google sheet. I made both the google doc and google sheet public "anyone with the link can access". However, when I ran it, it says "Exception: Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)" What am I doing wrong? I tried making both the sheet and doc public so anyone with the link can access. Still getting the same error.
function getTextFromDoc() {
  var docId = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KuEhKWTCqLY4mlT1cUHLU3sQbVR2wuS6-QPo8XUFvzw/edit?usp=sharing'; // Replace with your Google Doc ID
  var bookmarkId = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KuEhKWTCqLY4mlT1cUHLU3sQbVR2wuS6-QPo8XUFvzw/edit?pli=1#bookmark=id.mfymbqmkxh1i'; // Replace with your Bookmark ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var bookmarks = doc.getBookmarks();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
    if (bookmarks[i].getId() === bookmarkId) {
      var startElement = bookmarks[i].getPosition().getElement();
      var body = doc.getBody();
      var text = '';
      var started = false;

      // Iterate through all elements in the document
      for (var j = 0; j < body.getNumChildren(); j++) {
        var element = body.getChild(j);
        if (element === startElement) {
          started = true;
        }
        if (started) {
          if (element.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
            text += element.asParagraph().getText() + '\n';
          } else if (element.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) {
            text += element.asText().getText() + '\n';
          }
          // Stop at the next heading or the end of the document
          if (element.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH && element.asParagraph().getHeading() !== DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      // Paste text into Google Sheet
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(text.trim()); // Set the content in cell A1
      break;
    }
  }
}




The problem is that the script is using
openById but the document URL instead of the id is passed as parameter. Use openByUrl.
